# Finding the bounding box for a shape in VML

Tags: javascript, bounding-box, vml

How to find the bounding box values of a shape in VML using javascript?

For example consider the following shape element,

`<v:shape style="HEIGHT: 200px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 1px; TOP: 1px; WIDTH: 200px" coordsize = "1000,1000" fillcolor = "green" path = " m1,50 l1,1,200,200,1,0 e"></v:shape>`

In the above VML element, coordsize attribute represents height and width of the element can anyone explain how the coordsize attribute is set to a VML element by default.

In SVG, we can find the bounding box of a shape in javascript using getBBox() method. Is there any method available to get the bounding box values for a VML element in javascript?

We are not using any third party javascript plug-ins, we are only using javascript.